# Get User Language in Visualforce without controller

Tags: visualforce, user, global-variables

I have a Visualforce page without a controller and I would like to get the user LanguageLocaleKey value without having to add a controller (I know it can be done in Apex using UserInfo.getLanguage())

I tought it could be done using the $User global variable

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_user.htm

but if I try to put {!$User.LanguageLocaleKey} in the Visualforce page I get an error:

Error: Field LanguageLocaleKey does not exist. Check spelling

Is it possible to do it without a controller ?

Is there a reference of the available fields for global variable $User ? The  documentation link above is not really helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like language field is not available via $User global variable. Here is a knowledge article about it

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000205451&language=en_US

I checked for the available values for user and Language is not one of them. However there are other ways to implement this

1. Use Remote object and query the languageISOCode from there

   < apex:page>

   ```
   <  apex:remoteObjects jsNamespace="RemoteObjectModel">
     <  apex:remoteObjectModel name="User" jsShorthand="userRec"
           fields="Id,LanguageLocaleKey">
       </apex:remoteObjectModel>
   </apex:remoteObjects>

   <input type="button" onclick="fetchUsers();" value="MyButton"/>

   <script>
       var fetchUsers = function(){
           // Create a new Remote Object
           var ur = new RemoteObjectModel.userRec();
           var userID = '{!$user.id}';
           // Use the Remote Object to query for 10 warehouse records
           ur.retrieve({where: {Id: {eq:userID}}, limit: 10 }, function(err, records, event){
               if(err) {
                   alert(err.message);
               }
               else {
                   console.log(records[0].get('LanguageLocaleKey'));
               }
           });
       };
   </script>
   ```
2. Use SFDC JS Toolkit to query it (JS Wrapper for APIs). Connection.js

Answer (score 3):

**Using Labels**

We came across this trick when trying to fix the same limitation with Formula Fields.

- Create a Label - "CurrentLanguage"
- "Translate" that label so that the contents for each entry matches the country code of that langauge.

  - E.g. for English, set Label.CurrentLanguage to en-US
  - for French, set Label.CurrentLanguage to fr
- Leave the translations alone for any language you want to fall back to your default language.

The label can then be referenced where-ever any other label can be referenced, and is set to the language of the current user as defined by the translations you've set up.

**Using a Custom Field on User**

Alternatively, if you don't like the slightly "hacky" nature of using labels in this way (for the record, I do like it, as it gives you the defaulting), you can use a custom field on User...

- Create a new custom field on User "CurrentLanguage"
- Write a trigger on both BeforeInsert and BeforeUpdate that sets CurrentLanguage to the value in LanguageLocaleKey
- Backfill the new custom field on User so it contains the value for records that already exist.
- Where-ever you *would* have referenced LangaugeLocaleKey, you can now reference CurrentLanguage.

Comment: Note on the latter strategy that you would need a backfill batch.

Answer (score 0):

There is a one line solution to get current User language inside the VFP.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false"  standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false">
    <html>
        <body>
            <script>
                const language = '{!TEXT($User.LanguageLocaleKey)}';
                console.log(language); // printed en_GB
                const languageConverted = '{!TEXT($User.LanguageLocaleKey)}'.split('_')[0].toUpperCase(); 
                console.log(languageConverted); // printed EN
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Cheers!